# Is there a name for functions that chooses and returns one of its arguements by one of its arguements like "switch"?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am making functions that work like switch.

For example, it receives four arguements. The first arguement is one of 'a','b','c', and it works like below.

```js
(s, o1, o2, o3)=>{
  if(s==='a'){
    return o1 
  } else if (s==='b'){
    return o2 
  }else if (s==='c'){
    return o3 
  }
}
```

I have several functions that work like this, and would like to know if there is name for these, so that at least I can place them in one dir

Comment: I would call this type of function a `selector` function.